# Not able to select width of blocks inside of cover block

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I am using a blank theme with the theme.json for gutenberg blocks. When I create a cover block and select any block inside of my cover block it doesn't give me the option the select the width properties. So for all of my content inside of my cover block it is always inside of my regular content width.

I have already enable the wide content width with the

```
   "layout": {
        "contentSize": "800px",
        "wideSize": "1000px"
    },
```